# check whether a particular client (with ip1, port1) is connected to socket or not?

Tags: sockets, udp, ip

This is a basic client server program on UDP. if client 1 sends a data client 2 will receive and vice versa.

```
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

//bind the socket to localhost port 1902
if (bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) 
{
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Listener on port %d \n", PORT);


if (listen(master_socket, 3) < 0)
{
    perror("listen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//accept the incoming connection
addrlen = sizeof(address);
puts("Waiting for connections ...");

while(TRUE) 
{
    //clear the socket set
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);

    //add master socket to set
    FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
    max_sd = master_socket;

    //add child sockets to set
    for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++) 
    {
        //socket descriptor
        sd = client_socket[i];

        //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list
        if(sd > 0)
            FD_SET( sd , &readfds);

        //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
        if(sd > max_sd)
            max_sd = sd;
    }

    //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL , so wait indefinitely
    activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

    if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR)) 
    {
        printf("select error");
    }

    //If something happened on the master socket , then its an incoming connection
    if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds)) 
    {
        if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands
        printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d \n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));

    ....
    ....
    //what has to be done here to check a client with IP1, Port 1 is already connected? //
    ....
    ....
    }

    }
```

In this program, i get a message

```
New connection , socket fd is 4 , ip is : 127.0.0.1 , port : 44851 
Welcome message sent successfully
Adding to list of sockets as 0
New connection , socket fd is 5 , ip is : 127.0.0.1 , port : 44852 
Welcome message sent successfully
Adding to list of sockets as 1
```

After this message i want to check if a particular client with IP1, PORT 1 is connected or not? for example to check if client with ip 127.0.0.1 and port 44852 is already connected?  if connected print, required client is already available. Can anyone suggest me a way for this?

Comment: You said you were using UDP, but this code is for TCP instead.  You cannot use `listen()` and `accept()` with UDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty obvious how to do this.  You are storing client information in a list.  So simply loop through the list checking if the ip/port reported by `accept()` is already in the list, adding it if not.  Just make sure to keep the list up to date whenever a client disconnects.